# how do i print different titles in different cards using an api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

i was trying to print different titles obtained by jsonplaceholder onto different cards using jquery and javascript

here's the HTML section:

```
<div class="album py-5">
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">     
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

here's the JS:

```
//starts at 14:43, sat 21/9/2019

//jsonph

const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=3';

async function getDataFromCinemasAPI() {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i--) {
        $('.card-text').html((data[i]["title"]));
    }    
}

getDataFromCinemasAPI();
```

but the result that i get is the same title for the three different cards,
sorry for the long html :D

Comment: Why `i--` instead of `i++` in the for loop? Negative indexes should be throwing you an error in the console, since they will all resolve to `undefined`.

Comment: Well if you use the class as a selector `$('.card-text')` instead of a unique id for each card, then yes, that tends to happen :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code updated all cards simultaneously on every iteration and there fore what you see in the end is the list title on all cards. You can simply do this:

```
$('.card-text').eq(i).html((data[i]["title"]));
```

Though this is not best way as you always query the DOM. An optimization would be to store the collection of cards in a variable:

```
let cards = $('.card-text');

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    cards.eq(i).html((data[i]["title"]));
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i solved with your method, have a great day <3

Comment: Please approve. Also vote the answer below as it is also good

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues in your logic. Firstly you're decrementing `i` when looping, which is fine if you're going backwards through the array, but you're trying to go forwards so use `i++`.

Secondly, you need to use `eq()` to get the specific `.card-text` element by its index. Your current logic would overwrite all elements in every loop iteration. Try this:

```js
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=3';

async function getDataFromCinemasAPI() {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $('.card-text').eq(i).html(data[i]["title"]);
  }
}

getDataFromCinemasAPI();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="album py-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="btn-group">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="btn-group">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="btn-group">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Taking this a step further, I would suggest you build the `.card-text` elements dynamically instead of hard coding them, otherwise you will have issues if the API ever returns anything other than 3 objects in the array.

Comment: thanks!, i solved with the eq() method, but i used 3 todos from jsonph just for seeing if it worked, now i'll search a method for creating a cards dynamically, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="album py-5">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="card-text1">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="card-text2">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">     
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="card-text3">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>













for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $('.card-text'+i).html((data[i].title));
}
```

you are using same calss name so just you difference class name the issue will solve